# jQuery UI and jQuery computability when upgrading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When updgrading to jQuery-1.7.1 (from 1.4.2) do I need to updgrade jQuery-UI?

The project is really heavy so I would like to listen to expert opinions on how to move from this point.

Comment: I don't think there are any issues but why don't you upgrade both?

Comment: Did it. Seems like no problems for me at all. However everything is possible if you don't know the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/01/jquery-ui-1-8-17/

"The 1.8.17 release also brings support for jQuery 1.7.1."

Answer (score 1):

Actually jQuery UI is stable for jQuery 1.3.2+

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend upgrading, as there are quite a few bug fixes.  That said right next to the version number it shows the jQuery versions supported.  http://jqueryui.com/ jQuery UI is backwards compatible quite a few versions.